# Как создать объект из массива объектов c одинаковыми ключами?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив. Объектов в массиве может быть больше, и в каждом объекте намного больше пар ключ:значение.Нужно что бы динамически на основании названия ключа создавался объект с массивами {name: [20, 23, 20]}, и все значения с таким же ключем из объектов записывались в этот массив.

```
const data = [{name: 'Igor', age: 20}, {name: 'Vasya', age: 23},{name: 'Ivan', age: 20}];
```

И на выходе получалось это. Что бы не в ручную указывать что взять, и куда записать, а автоматически

```
const newData = {name: ['Igor', 'Vasya', 'Ivan'], age: [20, 23, 20]}
```

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки сделать это и с чем возникли сложности?

Comment: *А на выходе нужно получить `const newData = {{name: ['Igor', 'Vasya', 'Ivan']}, age: [20, 23, 20]}`* - Такой объект в js не может существовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function group(data) {
  return data.reduce((previous, current) => {
    Object.keys(current).forEach(key => { previous[key] = [...(previous[key] ?? []), current[key]]; });
    return previous;
  }, {});
}

const data = [
  { name: 'Igor', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Vasya', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Ivan', age: 20 }
];
console.log(group(data));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает! Всего вам наилучшего за помощь!!

Comment: @Серёга чуть удобнее сделал. Взгляните еще.

Comment: Спасибо! А не могли бы вы объяснить как это работает?.. Теряюсь после того как запускается цикл по ключам объекта... Хочу разобратся и понять, что бы в будущем не просить помощи... может на статью какую носом ткнёте.

Comment: @Серёга `data.reduce` проходит по всем элементам массива `data` принимая значение `{ }` в начале который я задал в конце функции и меняющая значение с помощью функции который задаю в начале. `previous` это значение который пришло от как результат предыдущей итерации, а `current` текущий элемент массива. В функции я получаю все ключи текущего элемента и значение каждого ключа добавляю к соответствующей значении предыдущего расчета. Ещё маленький нюанс -  что если в предыдущем расчете значение ключа не существует, то я задаю его как пустой массив.

Comment: @Серёга пошагово этот расчет выглядит так - `{ }`, `{ name: [ ] }`, `{ name: [ 'Igor' ] }`, `{ name: [ 'Igor' ], age: [ ] }`, `{ name: [ 'Igor' ], age: [ 20 ] }`, `{ name: [ 'Igor', 'Vasya' ], age: [ 20 ] }`, `{ name: [ 'Igor', 'Vasya' ], age: [ 20, 23 ] }`, `{ name: [ 'Igor', 'Vasya', 'Ivan' ], age: [ 20, 23 ] }`, `{ name: [ 'Igor', 'Vasya', 'Ivan' ], age: [ 20, 23, 20 ] }`, ...

Comment: Спасибо! за ваши знания

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос,  то вам нужен `reduce()`

```js
const data = [{name: 'Igor', age: 20}, {name: 'Vasya', age: 23},{name: 'Ivan', age: 20}];

const result = data.reduce((acc, { name, age }) => ({
  name: [...acc.name, name],
  age: [...acc.age, age],
}), { name: [], age: [] })

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Cпасибо. Но мне нужно динамически определить каждый ключ, создать новый объект с каждым ключем, а значением каждого ключа будет массив с теми свойствами по которым совпадает ключ вкаждом объекте, как то так

Comment: @Серёга не совсем понятно что вы хотите, исправьте код в своем вопросе на валидный js

Comment: Поправил вопрос